# Flutter app release build failing due to firebase_core plugin after migrating to flutter 2

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

After migrating to flutter two, I upgrated the android gradle and compiled sdk to latest.
my flutter app is running fine in debug mode, but when trying to build for release mode I got this error :

```
firebase_core: 1.5.0
```

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileReleaseAidl'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/user/Desktop/flutter1sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.5.0/android/local.properties'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

The plugin firebase_core could not be built due to the issue above.

and the gradle wrapper version

```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-   7.0.2-all.zip
```

after a lot of searching most of the answers where suggesting to manipulate grade version

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'





apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
compileSdkVersion 29

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.app.aumet"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
}

signingConfigs {
   release {
       keyAlias 'aumet' //keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
       keyPassword 'aumet_P@$sw0rd' //keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
       storeFile file('aumetKeyStore')  //keystoreProperties['aumetKeyStore'] ? file(keystoreProperties['aumetKeyStore']) : null
       storePassword 'aumet_P@$sw0rd' //keystoreProperties['storePassword']
   }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        //signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

}

```
flutter {
source '../..'
```

}

```
dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
```

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Got it issue before what I did is create a new flutter app '''flutter create .''' and move the files there. The reason i did that because on flutter 2.0 they implemented some default files and codes for andriod and ios files

Comment: @RaineDaleHolgado thank you for your answer, I am going to try this

Comment: @RaineDaleHolgado tried the suggested solution but it did not work :/